# Any method to remove unwanted space in grammar rule?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to add a special type of function to my antlr grammar called Window function. My Grammar looks something like this :

```
 stat: expression;
equation: expression relop expression;

expression:
    multiplyingExpression ((PLUS | MINUS) multiplyingExpression)*;

multiplyingExpression:
    powExpression ((TIMES | DIV) powExpression)*;

powExpression: signedAtom (POW signedAtom)?;

signedAtom:
    PLUS signedAtom
    | MINUS signedAtom
    | winfunc
    | func
    | iffunc
    | atom;

atom:
    scientific
    | string_literal
    | id
    | constant
    | LPAREN expression RPAREN;
string_literal: STRING;

scientific: SCIENTIFIC_NUMBER;

constant: PI | EULER | I;

variable: VARIABLE;

func: funcname LPAREN expression (COMMA expression)* RPAREN;
iffunc:
    'if' LPAREN equation COMMA expression COMMA expression RPAREN;
funcname: variable;

relop: EQ | GT | LT;

LPAREN: '(';

RPAREN: ')';

PLUS: '+';

MINUS: '-';

TIMES: '*';

DIV: '/';

GT: '>';

LT: '<';

EQ: '==';

COMMA: ',';

POINT: '.';

POW: '^';

id: '[' idx ']' {console.log($idx.text);};
idx:
    {(this.antlrHelper.isMetric(this.getCurrentToken().text))}? metricid
    | {(this.antlrHelper.isDimension(this.getCurrentToken().text))}? entityid
    | unknownid;
// metricid | entityid | unknownid;
metricid: VARIABLE;
entityid: VARIABLE;
unknownid: VARIABLE;
VARIABLE: VALID_ID_START VALID_ID_CHAR*;

fragment VALID_ID_START: ('a' .. 'z') | ('A' .. 'Z') | '_';

fragment VALID_ID_CHAR: VALID_ID_START | ('0' .. '9') | '.';

SCIENTIFIC_NUMBER: NUMBER ((E1 | E2) SIGN? NUMBER)?;

fragment NUMBER: ('0' .. '9')+ ('.' ('0' .. '9')+)?;

fragment E1: 'E';

fragment E2: 'e';

fragment SIGN: ('+' | '-');
STRING: '"' StringCharacters? '"';
fragment StringCharacters: StringCharacter+;
fragment StringCharacter: ~["\\] | EscapeSequence;
// §3.10.6 Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals
fragment EscapeSequence: '\\' [btnfr"'\\] | OctalEscape;

fragment OctalEscape:
    '\\' OctalDigit
    | '\\' OctalDigit OctalDigit
    | '\\' ZeroToThree OctalDigit OctalDigit;

fragment ZeroToThree: [0-3];
fragment OctalDigit: [0-7];
WS: [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
```

It is taking normal functions. For windows function, I've added following rule :

```
winfunc:
    WINDOW winfuncname LPAREN winMetricId COMMA scientific COMMA scientific RPAREN;

WINDOW: 'Window_';

winfuncname:
    variable;

winMetricId: '[' winMetricIdx ']';

winMetricIdx:
    {(this.antlrHelper.isMetric(this.getCurrentToken().text))}? metricid
    | otherid;

otherid: VARIABLE;
```

On parsing

> Window_ADD

it is parsing it into func rule but I want my grammar to parse it to winfunc rule.

> Window_ ADD

it is parsing it into winfunc but I don't want that extra space to be there. How can I make Window_ADD parse to winfunc rule instead of Window_ ADD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

**1.** If you know exactly which function names (terminals) will be used, you may simply change your rule:

`WINDOW: 'Window_';`

to

`WINDOW: 'Window_ADD';`

If you want to add more functions, say, Window_DEL, just add one more terminal to this rule:

`WINDOW: 'Window_' ('ADD' | 'DEL');`

or

`WINDOW: 'Window_';
 WINDOW_ADD: WINDOW 'ADD';
 WINDOW_DEL: WINDOW 'DEL';`

**2.** In case function names are unknown, you may want to use wildcards to determine a terminal:

`WINDOW: 'Window_' VALID_ID_CHAR+;`

In this case the type of a function is determined during the phase of semantic analysis.